# Complex valued calculations using Cython

Tags: cython

I am trying to do complex number calculations using cython.
In the example code I would like to calculate the complex exponential function of a complex number. The problem is that I do not know how to multiply my integer by the imaginary unit.
Multiplying by python's imaginary unit 1.0j raises errors while executing cython.

Here is my code:

```
cdef extern from "math.h":
    double complex cexp(double complex)

def testfunction():
    cdef double n
    n=3
    cdef double complex res
    res=cexp(n*1.0j)
    return res
```

And here is the error message:

> complex.c:678:3: note: expected ‘complex double’ but argument is of type ‘__pyx_t_double_complex’

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all, try reporting the full stack trace of the compilation. On my machine, I get a very helpful:

> implicit declaration of function ‘cexp’
>   [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]

It turns out you're including the wrong header. `cexp` is declared in `<complex.h>`, see the [docs](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/complex/cexp).

Simply change your code to

```
cdef extern from "complex.h":
    double complex cexp(double complex)
```

and you'll be fine.